# How did the Terrorists find out when and where Doc would be?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In an early scene of *Back to the Future*, Doc is

> shot by the terrorists whom he 'scammed' the plutonium off of

It's feasible that the terrorists would be able to find out that Doc lived in Hill Valley.  However, it seems mighty unlikely that they could figure out **Doc's exact location *and* the time he was going to be there.**

All we get in the movie is Doc muttering a bit about the fact that they found him and he doesn't know how.

So, my question is:

**How did the terrorists determine Doc's exact whereabouts and when he would be there?**  I'm open to accepting any information from the producers outside the movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Back-Future-George-Gipe/dp/0552127744) the terrorists had been following the Doc for several days and were well aware of his likely movements:

> *We’ll kill him tonight,” Sam continued. “Headquarters has decided it’s not worth it to bring him in for questioning. You two tail him for the rest of the day. **Chances are he’ll end up at the garage he uses for an office or at Twin Pines Mall. He’s been spending a lot of time there recently, usually late at night.***